# what is the difference [pandas.read_csv(filename) ]and [pandas.DataFrame.from_csv(filename)]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I am trying to read it and manipulate it.

However I notice one difference between the aforementioned methods as follow:

```
myDF = pandas.read_csv(filename)
```

will give me the dataframe indexed with integer from 0 to len(myDF)

```
    A    B    C    D
0   rr   gg   hh   kk
1   rr   gg   hh   kk
2   rr   gg   hh   kk
3   rr   gg   hh   kk
```

while using the following method:

```
myDF = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv(filename)
```

will result in:

```
     B    C    D
A
rr   gg   hh   kk
rr   gg   hh   kk
rr   gg   hh   kk
rr   gg   hh   kk
```

So it is clear that the last method took the first column as an index.
But my questioin is WHY.
Aren't the two methods supposed to be the same?
What do I miss here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is given in [the documentation for `DataFrame.from_csv()` -](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-from-csv)

> Read CSV file (**DISCOURAGED**, please use `pandas.read_csv()` instead).
>
> It is preferable to use the more powerful `pandas.read_csv()` for most general purposes, but `from_csv` makes for an easy roundtrip to and from a file (the exact counterpart of to_csv), especially with a DataFrame of time series data.
>
> This method only differs from the preferred `pandas.read_csv()` in some defaults:
>
> - **`index_col` is 0 instead of `None` (take first column as index by default)**
> - parse_dates is True instead of False (try parsing the index as datetime by default)

(Emphasis mine)

As you can see for [`pandas.read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) the index_col defaults to `None` so you get `0` to `len(DataFrame)` as index, whereas in `pandas.DataFrame.from_csv()`, `index_col` defaults to `0` , so it takes first column as default.

As explained in the documentation, I would recommend using the more powerful `pandas.read_csv()` than `pandas.DataFrame.from_csv()` .